# How to merge all columns in a DataFrame except the first into one column and drop empty rows? Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a large dataframe with multiple columns, and want to merge all values  from all columns except the first one into one new column (`'New'`). Then drop rows for which `'New'` is empty.

The `DataFrame` looks something like this (row `'C'` is empty):

```
    'Column1'  'Column2'  'Column3'  'Column4'  'Column5'  ...
0    A          a
1    B                     b
2    C
3    D          d
4    E                                e
5    F                                           f
6    G                     g
7    H                                h
...
```

The result I am looking for is this:

```
    'Column1'  'New'
0    A          a
1    B          b
2    D          d
3    E          e
4    F          f
5    G          g
6    H          h
...
```

So the first column remains as it is and all other columns are merged into the column `'New'`. Since row `C` contains no value, it is dropped from the final `DataFrame`.

What would be the most efficient way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can using `sum`

```
df['New']=df.iloc[:,1:].sum(1)
```

Comment: Thanks. But when I do this, df['New'] contains only zeroes:  
0        0.0

1        0.0

2        0.0

3        0.0

4        0.0

5        0.0

6        0.0

7        0.0

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
df['New'] = df.loc[:,1:].sum(1)
df1 = df[['column1','New']]
print df1[df1.New != '']
```

Comment: Thanks for the note. I'll updated the answer accordingly.